# GAGA proof, flat couple

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am struggling to understand the proof of lemma 6 in Serre's GAGA.

why does coherence of $\mathscr{F}$ imply Hom($\mathscr{F}^{h}$,$\mathscr{G}^{h}$)= Hom($\mathscr{F}_x$$\otimes$$\mathscr{H}_x$,$\mathscr{G}_x$$\otimes$$\mathscr{
H}_x$)
where $\mathscr{F}^h$ is defined as definition 2 in paper.

and why is $i_x $: Hom($\mathscr{F}_x$,$\mathscr{G}_x$)$\otimes$$\mathscr{H}_x$$\rightarrow$Hom($\mathscr{F}_x$$\otimes$$\mathscr{H}_x$,$\mathscr{G}_x$$\otimes$$\mathscr{
H}_x$)
bijective provided that ($\mathcal{O}_x$, $\mathcal{H}_x$) is a flat couple (meaning $\mathcal{H}_x$/$\mathcal{O}_x$ is $\mathcal{O}_x$ flat).

you can find GAGA here:
https://math.berkeley.edu/~reb/courses/256A/

any hints to just some of the above questions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is proposition 21 in the mentioned text.